# How to use a tuned Random Forest Regressor (post validation and testing) to forecast the future values for a univariate time series?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, random-forest

I have a three-year univariate time series dataset with weekly data entries. I have split the series into a training set (2 years of data) and a testing set (data from the final year). I have trained and optimised a random forest regressor model. Please note that I have used lags during the model. I now want to forecast six months into the future, but I am confused about how that would be possible.

Please answer the above question keeping in mind that I do not have the option to use FBProphet etc., as of now.

Comment: Does your model predict six months forward, or the next week?

Comment: The data used has weekly granularity.  Just providing a little more information, the data ranges from 01-Aug-2019 till 31-Jul-2022.  Training set comprises of the data from 01-Aug-2019 till 31-Jul-2021 while data from 01-Aug-2021 till 31-Jul-2022 forms the test set. I want to predict from 01-August-2022 till 31-Dec-2022.